# gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: C:\Users\xxxx) while trying to load binding.gyp

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I have followed [these steps](https://magento-research.github.io/pwa-studio/venia-pwa-concept/setup/) to install PWA.

But when trying to install build tools and configure the python dependency, we are facing this issue in windows 10.

> gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: C:\Users\xxxx) while trying to load binding.gyp
>
> gyp ERR! configure error
>
> gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1

And also we have tried the same steps in ubuntu system and it results the following error.

> make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

How to fix this?